# It's raining 'Yearling' badges

Tags: bug, yearling-badge

[image]

I am getting a new batch of these roughly every 30 minutes after I've made my first post on Meta Stack Overflow a couple of hours ago.

Any thoughts on that, anybody?

Comment: Extra: maybe the time you post on MSO it syncs SO rep with MSO rep, so you get >200*10 at once.

Comment: @user202729 AFAIK, the first time the user *accessed* the meta site, that's when the meta profile was *created* and then synced from the main site.